# pytest - How to execute a function after specific tests

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures, test-fixture

I have some tests organized in several classes. I already have a test fixture with scope=class so that it would run before suite(class) of tests. However, I need to execute a function after some specific tests. Lets say I have 100 tests in a class, I already have a fixture that will execute a function before these tests, but I also want to run a function after 2-3 of these tests.

What is the best approach to achieve that? Can it be done with fixtures or anything else ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, write a fixture that will execute after a test finishes:

```
@pytest.fixture
def foo():
    yield
    print("do stuff after test")
```

Docs: [Fixture finalization / executing teardown code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code)

Now mark each test that should invoke this fixture with `usefixtures("foo")`:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("foo")
def test_spam():
    ...
```

Docs: [Use fixtures in classes and modules with `usefixtures`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#use-fixtures-in-classes-and-modules-with-usefixtures)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Override12 if that answer is exactly what you were looking for, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the python's built-in unittest module you can override the `tearDown` method to run something after each test in a class.

If you are using pytest's framework and using pytests fixtures, you can use the `yield` keyword in your fixtures.

It's documented in https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#teardown-cleanup-aka-fixture-finalization.

Comment: I'm using pytest, however this doesn't help me, because I don't want to have a teardown after each test or after all the tests, I want a teardown after specific tests. For example I run 100 tests and I want to run a function after test 30, 45 and 70

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific tests you want to run after you could set up the tests in a .csv with different values for each test
for Example
(index)  (column)    (column)
Tests    Test#       Complete?
test 1    1          T
test 2    2          F

```
import pandas as pd 
#makes panda read your file and sets the variable as the data in the file
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv") 
#Gets the value from the column 'test#' and 'complete' and sets as a variable
Var1 = DataFrame.get_value("the number test you want to take", 'Complete?')
If Var1 = T 
   #Run the rest of your program here
#Then you can just repeat this for the other tests you want to check for
```

This isn't the prettiest solution but it works

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind. I was hoping for a more elegant solution to be honest. I imagined that decorators might be used to achieve something like this